# Audio seekBar Thread Problem?

Tags: android, multithreading, media-player, seekbar

Originally, I had a MediaPlayer mPlayers to play/pause/stop my Audio file. Now, I'm trying to add a seek bar for my media. I tried using Threads and this is what I came up with:

In onCreate() :

```
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mPlayer.seekTo(progress);
        }

////........Omitted Code..........\\\\

//At the very end of the method:
seekThread  = new Thread(this); //My Activity implements:Runnable
seekThread.start();
```

Then, I implemented a method `run()` to update my seek bar every 1 sec:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        while(mPlayer != null){
            int currentPosition = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.what = currentPosition;
            threadHandler.sendMessage(msg);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private Handler threadHandler = new Handler(){
    public void handleMessage(Message msg){
        seekBar.setProgress(msg.what);
    }
};
```

However, In my *HTC Magic*, the audio run inefficiently. Some words are repeated. It seems like the seek bar is going back a little bit every some time.

To make you understand the problem well, Let's say this: if the audio says that: abcdefghijklmn , then it will be like this: abccdeffghijjklmnn.

**Any improvement you suggest to my thread ? Am I doing it right?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure this will help, but try:

```
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
            boolean fromUser) {
        if (fromUser) {
            mPlayer.seekTo(progress);
        }
    }
```

Without this condition, mPlayer.seekTo(progress); is called every time you call seekBar.setProgress(msg.what);

Comment: Thanks. It seems the `fromUser` variable needed to be checked. Works great now.