# Seekbar is not moving

Tags: android, seekbar

i have a seekbar that should move while streaming from url but it's not automatically moving, but when you press on the seekbar it takes you where you should be. and my class doesnt fire run() function!

```
public void run() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
int currentPosition = 0;
int total = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
seekprogress.setMax(total);
while (mediaPlayer != null && currentPosition <total) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
        currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        return;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return;
    }
    seekprogress.setProgress(currentPosition);
}
```

}

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805449/audio-seekbar-thread-problem?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update UI elements only from the UI thread. Use runOnUiThread